# Can you access a model from inside another model in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, model

I am writing a webapp using CodeIgniter that requires authentication. I created a model which handles all my authentication. However, I can't find a way to access this authentication model from inside another model. Is there a way to access a model from inside another mode, or a better way to handle authentication inside CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, you don't want to create objects inside an object. That's a bad habit, instead, write a clear API and inject a model into your model.

```
<?php
// in your controller
$model1 = new Model1();
$model2 = new Model2();
$model2->setWhatever($model1);
?>
```

Comment: Is this a good practice? Because the user of Model2 has to know, that it is dependent on Model1.
What is the good practice?

Comment: Yes, better practice to "inject" the dependency, vs. initializing the Model2 inside Model1.

Comment: That doesn't sound good from a DRY standpoint. What if I have a function that changes an aspect of one model and triggers an action for another model?

Comment: I totally agree - model2 shouldn't go into model1 to start with. But if it's necessary, this is the best you can do.

Comment: This isn't good practice. If you have to use a model inside a model, then consider getting an instance of CI

Comment: What isn't good practice? Injecting dependencies **is** good practice!

Comment: @Till You're missing the forest for the trees.   It's perfectly fine to create a model inside another model -- if the two are going to be tightly linked.  It is not necessary to inject every dependency and to completely decouple every class from every other.  In fact, it's damned near impossible to do that.  What you need to do is find the fault lines in your system, the places where loose coupling can be reasonably achieved.  Isolate those modules and systems from each other and use dependency injection there.  Not everything needs be tested in isolation.

Comment: @DanielBingham I never said there weren't edge cases. There may be situations where what you said needs to be done, but honestly I cannot think of one. :) DI is definitely a good practice. You're also commenting on an answer I gave 3 years ago.

Comment: @till It may be three years old, but people still find it (I did).  So it's still open for discussion ;)   I'm mostly objecting to your first statement "In general, you don't want to create objects inside an object."  That's false.  Period.  Most OO Design Patterns require the creation of objects inside objects.  And you can't inject all of them.  Try using the factory pattern injecting everything created.  It beats the whole point of the pattern.  Now, it's more debateable as to whether it's a good practice to create a CI Model inside a CI Model...

Comment: @DanielBingham For testability of code, I object to introducing dependencies into an object which cannot be easily exchanged. That's all I am saying – and that's why I still stand by my original point that you should aim for DI.

Comment: @Till Dependency between _modules_ or _components_, not necessarily between objects.  Requiring that all objects used by any other object must be injected is just silly.  Most of the time you don't need to test objects in isolation.

Comment: I thought the whole idea of object oriented programming was the possibility to create object hierarchies the way you want them to be.

Comment: Why isn't it good practice to load objects inside objects? That can be very good practice. It all depends on your design and objectives. In fact most member variables will be objects. Most local variables will be objects.

Comment: I don't want to argue this any further because every couple months someone feels like expressing their own opinion. There is a thing called dependency injection (DI) which allows you and me to exchange dependencies of an object — if anything this an advantage for "maintainable code" (code quality) and LBNL for testing. Argueing that you don't need to test objects in isolation is fine, but then you're not unit testing anymore. And while you aim to test business logic, you then end up testing an entire framework and database underneath. This doesn't make it easier to find a bug in your code.

Answer (score 18):

It seems you can load models inside models, although you probably should solve this another way. See [CodeIgniter forums](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/49625) for a discussion.

```
class SomeModel extends Model
{
  function doSomething($foo)
  {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('SomeOtherModel','NiceName',true);

    // use $CI instead of $this to query the other models
    $CI->NiceName->doSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

Also, I don't understand what Till is saying about that you shouldn't create objects inside objects. Of course you should! Sending objects as arguments looks much less clear to me.

Comment: The complaint is that doing it that way unnecessarily creates a stronger dependency betweeen the two models.  

When you're testing, for example, it's nice to be able to give SomeModel a mock version of SomeOtherModel; you can't do that if the former is directly loading the latter.  
Or you modify the code later to use a different model with the same interface, such as when you're refactoring existing code to use a plugin system.

Comment: Google has an open source dependency injection framework. It's for Java but it explains the pros and some of the cons of dependency injection.

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/

Comment: @Rob Howard There is such a thing as taking dependency injection too far.  It's not necessary to inject every single object you use, as not every single object you use needs to be tested in isolation.  Rather you want to test systems and modules that work together as a whole and those need to be isolated from each other and injected.

Comment: I cannot believe this answer has 15 votes up, The reasoning behind it makes me cringe, This is the anti pattern of anti patterns(and no, it doesn't make it good by double negatives)

Answer (score 1):

Don't handle authentication in your model. Only use models to interface with your database, or ldap or whatever.

I created an Auth library that I use to manage authentication and authorization. You can access a library like this from your controllers.

Comment: I always put my oauth implementations inside a model, I don't like mucking up my controllers with authentication code

Comment: i create a MY_controller and do all oauth there.

Answer (score 1):

Loading a model within a model is now possible with the new CodeIgniter.