# How to extend a model from custom model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I created a model called Model_base extending from ci_model and added all common functions inside it

```
class Model_base extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{   
    parent::__construct();          
}
function create() {
    //do insert data into database
}

function read() {
    //do get data into database
}

function update() {
    //do update data into database
}

function delete() {
    //do delete data from database
}

}
```

Now I want to create a new model with extending base_model is it possible in CodeIgniter

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569252/how-to-inherit-a-model-from-another-model-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

Create a new model PHP file, and use:

```
class Model_New extends Model_Base {

   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
   }

}
```

Comment: where it should be placed,is it on same folder where other model are placed. thanks for your answer

Comment: Put this in a new file in the same directory as your other models

Comment: but its not working when its in same model directory, I guess we need to put it somewhere in core directory.

Comment: Save the model inside 'core' directory

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, just remember to call the `parent::__construct();` in the `constructor` of your new Model.