# PHP "out of memory" error when loading models within models in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, out-of-memory

I'm experiencing the following PHP error when loading models within another one:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 74448896) (tried to allocate 65484 bytes)
in /homepages/8/d315990455/htdocs/smileyou/Smileyou2.0/system/core/Loader.php on line 9
```

My PHP memory_limit is 120M (which I guess is more than enough for the kind of application I am developing).
To size the application, I count on 11 models and an average of 4-5 functions within each one. 150-200 lines of code each.

I have read that loading models within models in CodeIgniter (I do it in the class contructor always) is not a good practice, but until now, eveything just worked fine...
EDIT: If I try to load them in the function they are required instead of in the class constructor, it does not work either.

Has anybody experienced the same problem? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338/can-you-access-a-model-from-inside-another-model-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after hard debugging the code, I have got it working... and I document it for the community, just for the record:

It seems (I guess) like CodeIgniter has a *limitation* in the nesting level of model loading within models...

As I said, in my case I had 11 models (corresponding with a database table each).
The algorithms that I have to code require a lot of "nesting", since for example, many of my model functions could require 4 / 5 functions of other models, which in turn require others... and so on.

So, in this situation, I have fixed it by (hard) digging in the algorithm, and not loading some of the models (those that were generating the memory leak) even when they are required for some functions, because (I guess) they were already loaded in the "calling" (preceding) model.

That worked for me.
PS. I accept any more elegant approach for implementing such a complex algorithm in CodeIgniter though. So feel free to post it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Im not familiar with CI active record implementation, although it is a dated php 4 framework. In situations where you are running intensive database queries and producing active record models for those results try using raw database queries:

as i said im not familiar with CI although a quick look over the docs.. you should be able to do something like this:

```
return $this->db
        ->select($array)
        ->from('user')
        ->join('other','other.user_id = user.id','left')
        ->where($where)
        ->get()
        ->result();
```

Comment: For a modern php 5 framework with better Active Record try Laravel 4.0 its eloquent models are very performant...

Answer (score 0):

I was faced the same issue. **Increased memory_limit** from 8M to 256M in php.ini . Check your memory_limit and adjust as per the requirement.